# Does a navigation bar ever require constraints?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

So far, I have two distinct uses of a navigation bar in my app: **one produced by a Navigation Controller** with a View Controller embedded in it and **one added manually from the Object Library** into a different View Controller presented modally (since a modally presented view apparently doesn't inherit the navigation controller of the view under it).

**My question:** do either of these navigation bars require constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the one added by you, as it is managed by you. The other one is managed by `UINavigationController`. Also it wouldn't make sense for a modal controller to have the navigation bar of its presenter - you are showing an "extra" screen, not navigating the hierarchy. It is also worth mentioning that nothing stops you from presenting another `UINavigationController` modally with a separate navigation flow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The only thing I'm worried about is the Height constraint for the navigation controller added manually. All online info I've seen indicates that the height of the nav bar and tab bar are always the same across all devices, seemingly, but I still feel uneasy setting a strict height constraint. Is that just unjustified paranoia?

Comment: It seems to be :) it is actually true that the height is the same, and as follows - 20pt for status bar and 44pt for nav bar.